# Mindmap with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, mindmaps

I created a mindmap according to this example: `http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/`

Sometimes the branches contain too much information so that the map looks ugly like in this example here:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Main Topic}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {definition}
      child { node[concept] {this is a very long sentence ... very long sentence ... and it is even longer ...} }
      child { node[concept] {this is a very long sentence ... very long sentence ... and it is even longer ...} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] { node[concept] {Subtopic 1} }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Subtopic 2} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {Subtopic 3} }
    child[concept color=purple] { node[concept] {Subtopic 4} }
    child[concept color=brown] { node[concept] {Subtopic 5} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a possibility to create branches that are not displayed as a circle but just as a line like in this example, simply without the pictures?

[image]

Comment: yes there is a possibility. but alas I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Manually

One rather manual way would be to name the node with “Definition”, e.g. `(def)`, and use normal nodes that get positioned right of `def`.

I have created a style for these so called “non-concepts”:

- `rectangle` (default),
- `text width=12em`,
- `execute at begin node=\footnotesize` instead of `font=\footnotesize` (which does not perfectly combine with `text width`.

Further more I created a style `cncc east` for the to path from `def` to those non-concepts.
It consists of

- `out=0` and `in=180`, and
- a `to path`.

  As the usage of `to` inside the `to path` declaration failed, I fell back to the lower version `\tikz@to@curve@path` which calculates the path from

  - `tikztostart` and
  - `tikztotarget`

  which are set previously to the `.east` and respectively the `.south west` anchor.

  Additionally the `.south east` corner of the target node is used to finalize the line *below* the node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    non-concept/.style={
        rectangle,
        execute at begin node=\footnotesize,
        text width=12em,
    },
    cncc east/.style={% concept-non-concept-connection
                      % where the non-concept is east of the concept
        out=0,
        in=180,
        to path={
            \pgfextra{
                \edef\tikztostart{\tikztostart.east}
                \edef\tikztotargetB{\tikztotarget.south east}
                \edef\tikztotarget{\tikztotarget.south west}
            }
            \tikz@to@curve@path% needs \makeatletter and \makeatother
            -- (\tikztotargetB)
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white]
    node[concept] {Main Topic}[clockwise from=0]% named \___/ node
    child[concept color=green!50!black] { node[concept] (def) {definition} }
    child[concept color=blue]           { node[concept]       {Subtopic 1} }
    child[concept color=red]            { node[concept]       {Subtopic 2} }
    child[concept color=orange]         { node[concept]       {Subtopic 3} }
    child[concept color=purple]         { node[concept]       {Subtopic 4} }
    child[concept color=brown]          { node[concept]       {Subtopic 5} };

  \tikzset{
    every node/.style=non-concept,
    node distance=1ex,
  }
  \node[right=1cm of def, anchor=south west] (know)
    {What does each person know and not know about my topic?};
  \node[below=of know]                       (react)
    {How will each person react?
                      What concerns will I need to overcome?};
  \node[above=of know]                       (audi)
    {Who exactly is my audience?
      What is each listener's role and reason for attending?};

  \draw[
    line width=.8pt,
    shorten <=.06em,
    ]
        (def) edge[cncc east] (know)
              edge[cncc east] (react)
              edge[cncc east] (audi);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## (Kind of) automatically

I prefer the manual way as described above.

Setting the `edge of parent path` is not a big problem and is even easier.

But assigning the right styles at the right level is very annoying and one has to write up a custom `growth function`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    non-concept/.style={
        rectangle,
        text width=12em,
        text=black,
        align=left,
    },
    cncc east/.style={
        edge from parent path={
            (\tikzparentnode.east) to[out=0, in=180] (\tikzchildnode.south west)
            -- (\tikzchildnode.south east)
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white]
    node[concept] {Main Topic}[clockwise from=0]% named \___/ node
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
        node[concept] (def) {definition}
        [
            grow=right,
            sibling distance=14ex,
        ]
            child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {What does each person know and not know about my topic?}                            edge from parent[cncc east] }
            child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {How will each person react? What concerns will I need to overcome?}                 edge from parent[cncc east] }
            child[level distance=5cm] { node[non-concept] {Who exactly is my audience? What is each listener's role and reason for attending?} edge from parent[cncc east] }
        }
    child[concept color=blue]           { node[concept]       {Subtopic 1} }
    child[concept color=red]            { node[concept]       {Subtopic 2} }
    child[concept color=orange]         { node[concept]       {Subtopic 3} }
    child[concept color=purple]         { node[concept]       {Subtopic 4} }
    child[concept color=brown]          { node[concept]       {Subtopic 5} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your great answer! I took the first method and it works perfectly.