# Mind mapping in Freemind reducing vertical space

Tags: mindmaps

[image]

Please, I know this may not  be the right place. I am learning freemind to dram mind mapping. However, I am getting difficult to arrange the map in such away that it does not leave the gap at the top. I have tried ctrl + drag.
Attached is the screenshot.  I would like to use latex tikz mind mapping, but I have large visual maps.
regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you're using Ti*k*Z to draw the mindmap then this is the right place, but we need to see your code to help you where you're stuck. If you're using other software, then you should ask somewhere else.

Comment: If you a very new to LaTeX then I would not recommend starting with a "large visual map". Maybe better stick to https://www.yworks.com/products/yed or other mindmap tools.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. How can I attach screenshot?. I have checked, didnt find button to add

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced screenshot, instead of placing at the bottom, I placed at the top.

Comment: Dear Phelype Oleinik Dr. Manuel Kuehner, I am not new to latex, using it for my dissertation. I am interested to use tikz library. However, can tikz + latex draw biger diagram?. Let me try to use tikz to draw the diagram.

Comment: Is the whitespace in the image itself? Can't you just crop the image?

Comment: Are you arware of the **Chapter 60** in `http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf` (Mindmap Drawing Library)? Or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/? Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88159? Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611?

Comment: I recommend that you make clear what you want to achieve and ask a closer/narrower question (including a minimal working example, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). At the moment it is unclear if you want an exact copy of the screenshot or if this is just an example of the complexity,

Comment: Guys, Thank you very much for your reply. Let me work on it and will come back.

Comment: Torbjørn T.  Thank you for your reply, yes I can crop, but I have intensive learning using mind mapping. Having said that, I want to continue using LaTeX and will psot here if I have questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because kind of solved in comments.

Comment: Yes, please, close topic. Thank you, am working with LaTeX, then will post the answer here.